# Get RGB of JPG in Android

Tags: java, android, bufferedimage, javax.imageio, mobile-development

first of all thank for your time. I have a jar library which would be included as library in my Android Application.
This jar, among other things, is able to get the RGB values from a jpg image. This works perfectly in my java application but when I runs it in my Android application it does not work because the class `ImageIO.read(File file)` (Bufferedimage) does not implemented in Android.
I read something about using Bitmap class but i do not find out anything about it.

Could you help me with this method you find here below?

```
public static int[][][] getImageRgb(BufferedImage image) { 
int width = image.getWidth(); 
int height = image.getHeight();
int[][][] rgb = new int[height][width][3]; 
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) { 
for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) { 
int pixel = image.getRGB(j, i); 
rgb[i][j] = getPixelRgb(pixel); } 
} 
return rgb; 
}
```

Where getPixelRgb is a function aims this:

```
public static int[] getPixelRgb(int pixel) {
        // int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;
        int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
        int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
        int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;
        return new int[]{red, green, blue};
}
```

I really I do not know how to transform this methods for Android.

I look forward to hearing from you.
Thank a lot.

Comment: anything? really ? What about [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) ?

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I really do not know how to implement it

Answer (score 1):

What you need is in the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel(int,%20int)):

> int getPixel (int x, int y)
>
> Returns the Color at the specified location.

You can create a Bitmap from a resource in res/drawable folder or if you're downloading the image, you need to first save it to the device storage.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but should I use Bitmap android class? In which way?

Comment: I've updated the answer. If you provide more specific information I may help you further.

Comment: I wish you could help me. Tell me more about you want as further information. May I write in private?